# Novice to JS: How to properly call a recursive function in an HTML document?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm a bit confused on calling the function correctly in this HTML doc. What am I doing wrong? The function should return the sum of all numbers between 1 and whatever number entered on the input field but is returning NaN instead.
How do I assign and display the returned value from the function to the disabled input field?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Recursion</title>
    <script>
    let recursiveSum = (num) => {
        if (num === 1) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return num + recursiveSum(num-1);
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Find the sum of 1 to some number!</h1>
<form id="myForm" name="myForm">
  <input type="number" id="numInput" name="numInput" placeholder="Enter a positive number here" autofocus>
  <input type="text" id="sum" name="sum" disabled>
  <button type="button" onclick="recursiveSum(this.form.numInput.value);">Calculate! </button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your function doesn't `return` anything. So `+ recursiveSum(...)` means nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your function doesn't explicitly return any value so `undefined` is returned from function implicitly.

Also setting `value` in each recursive call doesn't make any sense. You should set the value after the result of all the recursion.

```js
const elm = document.getElementById("sum")

function btnClick(num){
  let recursiveSum = (num) => {
    if(num === 1) return 1;
    return num+recursiveSum(num-1)
  }
  elm.value = recursiveSum(+num)
}
```

```html
<h1>Find the sum of 1 to some number!</h1>
<form id="myForm" name="myForm">
  <input type="number" id="numInput" name="numInput" placeholder="Enter a positive number here" autofocus>
  <input type="text" id="sum" name="sum" disabled>
  <button type="button" onclick="btnClick(this.form.numInput.value);">Calculate! </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Well, this is the part where I get confused. I know how to return the value needed, what I don't understand is how do I incorporate this function into this html document? Am I using the document.getElementById() correctly?

Comment: Your solution gives incorrect sum, e.g. for 3, it gives back 5, when it should actually be 6.

Comment: @binibiningtinamoran You are using `document.getElementById()` not correctly because calling it in each recursive call doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @MaheerAli Is it important that this script is placed at the bottom of the HTML document?

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the computation from showing the value, so you can properly compute the sum. Once you got the sum, displaying it is easy.

```js
let recursiveSum = (num) => {
  if (num === 1) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return num + recursiveSum(num - 1);
  }
}

let showSum = (num) => {
    document.getElementById("sum").value = recursiveSum(num);
}
```

```html
<h1>Find the sum of 1 to some number!</h1>
<form id="myForm" name="myForm">
  <input type="number" id="numInput" name="numInput" placeholder="Enter a positive number here" autofocus>
  <input type="text" id="sum" name="sum" disabled>
  <button type="button" onclick="showSum(parseInt(this.form.numInput.value));">Calculate! </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! But where do I parse it? I think the function shall do a concatenation instead of addition.

Comment: @binibiningtinamoran I've moved out the parseInt in the onclick call, so I don't parseInt multiple times inside the function.